# Notes/Domino : Can I specify a default view when opening Notes DB by NOMAD?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I know I can specify the default view/frameset/navigator/etc in DB property setting when opening Notes DB by NotesClient or Web browser. I'd like to specify a default view when opening DB by NOMAD. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a frameset and in that frameset you compute the name of the view like this:

```
@If( @Platform = "iOS" : "Android" ; "YourNOMADView"; "YourDefaultView" )
```

If you want to replace the complete navigation and all other stuff, then you create 3 Framesets:

FramesetNOMAD - all views and navigation you want to show on NOMAD

FramesetDEFAULT - views and navigation for "normal" client.

MainOuter - one Frame, Content: Frameset, Formula:

```
@If( @Platform = "iOS" : "Android" ; "FramesetNOMAD"; "FramesetDEFAULT" )
```

Then you set your database to start with "MainOuter" in Notes client.

I am not 100% sure about the real values for Platform on iOs and Android Devices... need to test that before using my formula.

Comment: That's all I'd like to know. Thanks for your great help!!